# accessing elements of dynamic array of lists

Tags: c++, stdlist

So, I don't know how can I print elements of such a list.

```
list<int>* a;
a = new list<int>(4);
a[0].push_back(1);
a[0].push_back(3);
a[2].push_back(5);
a[2].push_back(7);

cout << a[0].front() << '\n';
cout << a[1].back() << '\n';
```

Firstly, I tried to print it via range-based for loop, but it didn't work either.

```
for(auto element: a[0]) cout << element << '\n';    // doesn't work
```

Comment: a = new list<int>[4];

Comment: `a` is a pointer to *one* list with four elements, all of them zero; only `a[0]` (a.k.a `*a`) is valid. Using any other index has undefined behaviour.

Comment: And please be more specific than "doesn't work".

Comment: When I tried to print out elements the program didn't do anything

Comment: I thought it is would be four elements of the array, every one blank list, but 'a = new list<int>[4]' is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to store a list of integer lists? Because this implementation will not work since you only have a list of integers and no push_back() operation is available for the elements.

Remove the index operator for all those push_back() operations and take out the index operator for the front() and back() as those are not available to the elements either.

Comment: Do you mean to define them with indexes, like `a[0] =`?

Comment: You can do that as well since you already allocated the space for elements by passing in 4 in the list constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `std::vector` instead of `new` (which should technically be `new[]` in this case anyway).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::list<int>> a(4);
    a[0].push_back(1);
    a[0].push_back(3);
    a[2].push_back(5);
    a[2].push_back(7);

    for (std::list<int> const& l : a) {
        for (int i : l) { 
            std::cout << i << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output

```
1 3

5 7
```